# Xcode 14 "switched" to older commit, how to get back more recent commits?

Tags: xcode, git

I am obviously in a panic, don't want to do anything (more) rash.
I did commit my work multiple times in Xcode.

I wanted to look at something I remember was in a month old version so I "Switched" to it.
[image]

Now when go to repositories it's only showing commits prior to the 1 month old version.
The latest commits are not there.

[image]

How can I just back to the last (most recent) commit?

Any assistance would earn my eternal gratitude.

Using Xcode 14.2 local repositories.

Comment: Thanks so much, I know I need to move the HEAD back and its technically possible, the instruction uses the terminal, but I am lost how to achieve this in Xcode?

Comment: I suspect that you can't. So you need to switch to console.

Comment: Ah, so I can just use git in terminal on the project folder?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go

Comment: Thank you, I will back up project file before touching anything.